# How to ensure user identity in Azure Function Call? ASP NET Core Web App

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I am building an ASP NET Core web application that will perform a delete operation for a user on a remote datastore. Currently, I have a frontend web app that communicates with Azure Functions to delete a user. I have a concern with security. How can I make sure the user is the logged-in user? Currently, in my ASP Net Core Web App, I have the user authenticate with AAD using Microsoft as an Identity Provider. From a client-side, the user is verified and taken care of. However, my app calls the Azure Functions endpoints. Is there an extra level of security that I could add. I only want to give my web app (registered in Azure) the ability to call the endpoints.

Comment: if you're using Azure AD as the identity, you can pass the token into Authorization header and validate it on your Azure Function too.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to authenticate your users. One is to use the App Services authentication options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad. This is by far the easier method.

If you need more control over things than what is available in the service, then you can implement validation within the Function itself as Thiago mentioned. Ben Morris did a fairly detailed post on how to implement your own OAUTH provider inside your Function App with C#: https://www.ben-morris.com/custom-token-authentication-in-azure-functions-using-bindings/ If you can take care of the validation in the Function's DI container, validation inside a specific function is fairly clean as seen in the post:

```
public class ExampleHttpFunction
{
    private readonly IAccessTokenProvider _tokenProvider;

    public ExampleHttpFunction(IAccessTokenProvider tokenProvider)
    {
        _tokenProvider = tokenProvider;
    }

    [FunctionName("ExampleHttpFunction")]
    public IActionResult Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "example")] HttpRequest req,  ILogger log)
    {
        var result = _tokenProvider.ValidateToken(req);

        if (result.Status == AccessTokenStatus.Valid)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Request received for {result.Principal.Identity.Name}.");
            return new OkResult();
        }
        else
        {
            return new UnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```